# Detecting if the person viewing the website is the developer

Tags: javascript, html, authentication

I have a view counter on my [website](https://quackduck.github.io/electric/) that plots the time spent by a viewer on the site to a [Thingspeak chart](https://thingspeak.com/channels/958651). I want it to not count my views. So it should detect me. I could maybe change the value of a boolean in Console but that isnt feasible. I thought about storing a cookie on my computer and the website would read it to see if it's me but then its crossite samesite stuff I don't understand. Then I thought about checking if the viewer's IP address is mine. Apparently you need server-side stuff for that and GitHub doesn't allow that. Any more ideas?

Comment: You need to define how you want to recognize the user which should not be counted. You could e.g. pass a parameter to the URL (`?do-not-count=1`), you could store a cookie, you could store a value in localStorage, you could use an IP-based identification (IPs usually change from time to time on a regular machine), you could read the UserAgent (the value which the browser sends automatically to identify itself). First, you need to decide that.

Comment: @ssc-hrep3 Hmmm... Expand on the UserAgent idea.

Comment: The problem with useragents is that they're not necessarily unique. If you use a commonly used browser, then it's pretty likely that others will have an identical useragent to yours.

Comment: UserAgents usually show what browser (version), web engine, OS, device type etc. is used. They are defined by the browser and sent along to the server as a request header. You can overwrite the UserAgent on the command line (e.g. with curl) or adapt it in the DevTools of e.g. Chrome. It's probably better to use a different approach in your case. The answer of @CertainPerformance with the localStorage approach looks interesting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A really simple hacky solution without using IP checking / backend logic would be to set a `localStorage` value to something that shouldn't exist normally. With the site loaded, open your browser console and assign something, eg

```
localStorage.userIsIshanGoel = 'yes';
```

Then, in the script on your page, just check that property before running the code that increments the view count:

```
if (localStorage.userIsIshanGoel !== 'yes') {
  incrementViewCount();
}
```

It's not foolproof - for example, someone could examine the source code of the page and set the property themselves, but if the view count is just for your personal informational use, that's quite unlikely to happen (and even then, that's only a single user).

Comment: Love this approach. Will keep this in my back pocket for sure.

Comment: If I want to test this, can I do so on a local site first? Localstorage sounds like cookies. Is it similar?

Comment: @IshanGoel Test this on a local site, you mean like on localhost? Yes, localStorage works on localhost as well.

Comment: The difference is that cookies are sent *to the server* with every request. In contrast, localStorage is client-side only, and doesn't get sent with requests. Cookies make authentication easy *if* you have back-end logic you can implement. localStorage exists for semi-permanent storage of data on the client's machine only.

Comment: @CertainPerformance No, I mean as in loading the file on my computer on a browser.

Comment: @IshanGoel Yes, it looks like localStorage works on `file://` protocols as well.

Comment: I have committed and pushed this suggestion. Waiting to see the changes.